# Не все браузеры устанавливают https после подключения ssl

Tags: javascript, html, css, ssl

Подключил к сайту ssl сертификат Let’s Encrypt через ISPmanager, chrome и яндекс на десктопе подключаются через https, проблема возникает в edge и мобильных chrome, safari (остальные не проверял), не устанавливается https, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Вопрос из разряда "почему не работает"? Мы не знаем. Нужна какая-то дополнительная информация. Очищали ли кэш на мобилке?

Comment: Обычно браузеры пишут причину прямо на странице с ошибкой

Comment: В адресной строке указан https? Или просто адрес? Если второе, то необходимо на сайте настроить переадресацию с http на https.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего нужно поставить переадресацию с http со значением "принудительная", либо попробовать в .htaccess Записать редирект:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-HTTPS} !1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```